# Why changing .py files do not influence behaviour of django website?

Tags: python, django, apache

**Here's the problem:**

In one of Django views.py I have the following code:

```
from kml_generator import KML_generator

@login_required(login_url='/dev/login')
def search(request):

    if request.POST:
        result,SF=Validate(request, Activities)
        val=result.values('id')        
        KML_generator(result1=val,user=request.user)
```

it basically imports module `kml_generator` and calls the class `KML_generator` from there. This class generates `.kml` file which is then shown on OpenLayers. It works as it should, but I want to change it.

**And now:**

Why when I change code inside the module `kml_generator` it do not affect the behaviour? I tried everything I even put there errors and it still works like charm....

**So here's the question:**

How to change it? Do a django have some kind of 'build', 'compile' inside? Do I need to call it to affect the code?

PS. It's all standing on Apache using wsgi.py

PS2. Ok, that's pathetic by me, but we got side company which developed for us a nice dynamic django website. And now I do not know why it doesn't work like I though it would.

Comment: Try restarting the apache webserver after code changes.

Comment: Did you restart apache? After "start" python keeps it's files in precompiled state in .pyc format next to your .py files.

Comment: It may also be better to subclass `KML_generator` and implement your changes that way.

Comment: If restarting doesn't help there's the chance you have some old pyc files on the server that stayed there after renaming the source file, to find any run `find . -type f -name "*.pyc"` or `find . -type f -name "*.pyc" | xargs rm -rf;` to remove them accordingly

Comment: `.pyc` are purely cached, bytecode-compiled versions of `.py` files. There is no need to remove them; the only thing they can do is waste a tiny bit of space if there has been some renaming.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to restart the Apache server for Django to pick up changes.

Python loads source files just once, when a module is imported. The compiled bytecode is then kept in memory. At import time, Python also caches the bytecode, in a `.pyc` file next to the original source file, you can verify that a new import has taken place by comparing timestamps on the `.py` and corresponding `.pyc` files.

A graceful restart should suffice; run `apache2ctl graceful` as root on your server.

In future, you may want to get yourself a development setup; running the same code (from a VCS, of course), but using the built-in Django development server:

```
python manage.py runserver
```

The Django development server does its best to reload code when you change it. This is a *development* feature only (watching files for changes costs performance).

Last but not least, try to avoid altering third-party libraries. Use subclassing or monkeypatching instead, and perhaps the upstream author would be willing to implement new features for you or accept patches. That way you don't have to maintain those changes yourself across versions either.